# Why would CreateAsync(user, password) sometimes fail? (Identity v2 MVC5)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using Asp.Net MVC5 with Identity v2 for authentication. The functions I've written for user creation worked perfectly during development. However, since I've published for production a couple of days ago, I'm **sometimes** getting exceptions for the CreateAsync(user, pass) method. Here is my simplified code:

```
 var store = new UserStore<SiteUser>(dc);
 var userManager = new UserManager<SiteUser>(store);

var user = new SiteUser
                {
                    UserName = email,
                    Email = email,
                    MemberID = member.MemberID
                };
var createResult = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, rawPassword);

if (!createResult.Succeeded)
    throw new Exception("User Creation Failed - Identity Exception");
```

my question is, why would I **sometimes** get this exception? In other words, what are the conditions in which this `CreateAsync` method would return `!createResult.Succeeded`?

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: I'm throwing the exception manually, as in the above code. Method just returns false for `createResult.Succeeded`. Other than that, it's sadly not open source yet.

Comment: You can check `Errors` property of the result : `createResult.Errors` to see why it didn't succeed.

Comment: Ok, didn't know that thanks. I modified my Exception log as the following and will post what's going wrong the first time I see it:

createResult.Errors.Aggregate("User Creation Failed - Identity Exception. Errors were: \n\r\n\r", (current, error) => current + (" - " + error + "\n\r"));

Comment: this was VERY helpful thank you. The error message was "User name XXXXX-XXX@hotmail.com is invalid, can only contain letters or digits". So yeah, I know the problem know. do you know how I can change this behavior, I need to be able to accept those hypens?

Comment: Ok, I extended the `UserManager` in a class I called `ApplicationUserManager` to include `AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false`. Thanks @alex-art, if you didn't point me out a way to debug this, I wouldn't be able to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @alex-art , I was able to figure out the problem. It was the rule defined in the `UserManager` class which didn't accept non-alphanumeric values in email / usernames. I extended `UserManager` in `ApplicationUserManager : UserManager` to include

`AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false`

to solve this.

I was able to identify the problem by looking at the `createResult.Errors` list (pointed out by @alex-art. I did this by changing my exception log to:

```
if (!createResult.Succeeded)
{
    var exceptionText = createResult.Errors.Aggregate("User Creation Failed - Identity Exception. Errors were: \n\r\n\r", (current, error) => current + (" - " + error + "\n\r"));
    throw new Exception (exceptionText);
}
```

Comment: I am so thankful to all parties here, as your dialog saved my bacon. I had no idea what I was doing wrong. Same problem. I'll make a note, also, of the improved exception logging!